# WP Query not showing all results all the time

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a wp website with lunch and dinner offers for the next day. The offers are entered as posts, are in there own category (id=4) and have two custom field value:
- menu_date - the date when the post should be visible
- menu_number - if it's lunch it's 1, if it's dinner is 2

I use this query to get the posts i need:

```
$args = array(
'post_type'  => 'post',
'cat' => 4,
'meta_key'=>'menu_number', 'orderby' => 'meta_value_num', 'order' => ASC );

$query = new WP_Query($args);

if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
while($query->have_posts()) {
    $query->the_post();

    $menu_date = get_post_custom_values( 'menu_date' );
    $menu_number = get_post_custom_values( 'menu_number' );
    $tommorow = date("dmY", time()+86400);

    if ( $tommorow == $menu_date[0] && has_post_thumbnail() ) {
         the_post_thumbnail('full', array( 'class' => 'img-responsive' ) );
             if ($menu_number[0] == 1) {
                 <a href="#">Get Lunch!</a>
             }
             else{
                 <a href="#">Get Dinner!</a>
             }
         the_title();
    }
}
} wp_reset_query();
```

Every day both lunch and dinner offers should be visible, but sometimes only lunch is shown, but after a few refreshes both are visible again.

Any way to improve the code so that this doesn't happen anymore? Thanks

Comment: What is `$data_meniu` ? Shouldn't it be `$menu_date` ?

Comment: Correct. Missed that one when I copied the code. (the variables were in Romanian initially) :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out:

I changed the $args like this. I added the menu_date here and I'm only retrieving the posts that have correct value.

```
$args = array(
'post_type'  => 'post',
'cat' => 4,
 'meta_query' => array(
                array(
                    'key' => 'menu_date',
                    'value' => "$tommorow"
                )),
 'meta_key'=>'ordine_meniu', 'orderby' => 'meta_value_num', 'order' => ASC ); 

 $query = new WP_Query($args);
```

Answer (score 0):

> Every day both lunch and dinner offers should be visible, but sometimes only lunch is shown, but after a few refreshes both are visible again.

It may be related to how you compute for tomorrow's date:

```
$tommorow = date("dmY", time()+86400);
```

Try changing it to as follows and see if that would work:

```
$tomorrow = date("dmY", strtotime("tomorrow"));
```

Comment: Seams to act the same. Still doesn't show both posts.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check both at once in a loop. Like this :

```
        `if ($menu_number[0] == 1) {
             <a href="#">Get Lunch!</a>
         }
         if ($menu_number[0] == 2){
             <a href="#">Get Dinner!</a>
         }`
```

If this doesn't solve the problem, try debugging the values of $menu_number and $menu_date. See what is coming.

EDIT:

The meta query args should be like this: $tommorrow was incorrect in your args

```
'meta_query' => array(
    array(
        'key' => 'menu_date',
        'value' => $tommorow
    )
)
```

For Date Query:

```
$tomorrow = date("dmY", time()+86400);
$args = array(
    'date_query' => array(
        array(
            'year'  => $tomorrow["year"],
            'month' => $tomorrow["mon"],
            'day'   => $tomorrow["mday"],
        ),
    ),
);
```

This will give you tomorrow's posts.

Comment: This doesn't have any effect. Even if I remove them. I edited the original post. I think I need to add the date test in the $args at the beginning, but I'm not sure how.